# Lowest percentage of non penalty goals scored by World Cup golden boot winners

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

With only the final match of the 2018 World cup remaining, Harry Kane of England has a commanding 3 goal lead cushion for winning the [Golden Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup_awards#Golden_Boot). Kane scored 6 goals in the tournament, 3 of which where from penalties, which means only 50% of his goals were not from the penalty spot.

What are the lowest percentages of the non-penalty goals scored by world cup golden boot winners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/44712435), Kane does in fact have the highest percentage of penalty goals (meaning lowest percentage of non-penalty goals) in a Golden Boot-winning tournament with his three penalties out of six goals (50%).

In second place is Portugal's Eusebio, scoring four penalties out of nine goals  in 1966 (44%).

In third place is Russia's Salenko, scoring two penalties out of six goals in 1994 (33%).